# Freezing columns on a large table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem in CSS, I have big table with many columns, I need to freeze some columns and when the page is scrolled it will not be moved but I can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want columns that don't scroll with the page (columns is the thing that goes down, not to the right). Do you want them to stay when you scroll horizontal or vertical?

## Vertical

This isn't possible with one table because the point of a table it to keep all cells of a single row (horizontal) always at the same height.

What you can try is to split the table into two (or more). Set the style for those columns that you don't want to scroll to `position: absolute` or the like. But you will face another problem: You will have to set the height of all rows of all tables to some fixed value; otherwise, the columns won't align properly.

If you need the values to stay fixed for vertical scrolling, try this: You could also use a JavaScript framework like jQuery to notice when the user scrolls the page and then *copy* the content of the cells. So while the cells actually move, the first visible cell always contains the same value.

## Horizontal

If you need to the first (few) column(s) fixed while scrolling horizontally (i.e. column headers like in Excel), use jQuery to iterate over the cells in the first column to get their size and position and then add absolutely positioned `div`s to the left of the table (just give the whole table some margin to make room for them).

Check [this blog post](http://fixed-header-using-jquery.blogspot.com/2009/05/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-and.html).

Comment: I must admit: Your answer is much more detailed :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply declare the position of your `<td>` that shall not be moved as fixed with CSS.

Example:

```
<html>
  <head><style type='text/css'>.noMove { position:fixed; }</style></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Column 1</td>
          <td class='noMove'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, that works perfectly well :D

Comment: You can also use the overflow property to cause the unfrozen bits to be scrollable.